# change CSS in external URL stylesheet - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress rating plugin that connects to an external URL stylesheet in order to display the ratings.

So I'd like to change the font-size of the stars that are displaying on my site.

I can see that the look of the font is defined in the following stylesheet and url: `https://publ.ratingz.com/app/FF897e.app.css`

The star font is using class `.rate-me-ratingz`

I've been trying to change the font size using this class together with `!important` tag, but I guess that will not work, right?

Is there any way to edit and customise this external stylesheet in this case?

Answer (score 0):

## No, it would work.

You just have to override the style.

**Method 1:**

Use `!important` as you mentioned. E.g. `.rate-me-ratingz {  font-size: 25px !important;  }`

**Method 2:**

Use a more specified rule. By adding an id, an additional class, or an element, it will override the rule. E.g.

- `html .rate-me-ratingz {  font-size: 25px;  }`
- `#page .rate-me-ratingz {  font-size: 25px;  }`
- `div.rate-me-ratingz {  font-size: 25px;  }`

**Method 3:**

Use an in-text style. This is more specified. E.g.

```
<head>
  <style>
    .rate-me-ratingz {  font-size: 25px;  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  ....
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, no luck yet, but will keep trying to find the correct tag. When  i do the change using the chrome inspector, it works just fine, but when I copy the exact same classes into my own CSS, the change won't show up at all.